# how i can add child node into existing parent node in xml using linq to xml

Tags: xml, linq-to-xml

suppose we have
XML FILE:
    `<COLLEGE>
     <location>
     <area> najafgrah </area>
     <!--want to add new child node pragmatically-->
     </location>
     </COLLEGE>`

HOW I CAN ADD NEW CHILD NODE ......

Answer (score 1):

Here is one example.

```
XElement doc = XElement.Parse(@"<COLLEGE> <location> <area> najafgrah </area>
</location> </COLLEGE>");

doc.Add(new XElement("location", new XElement("area", "area number 2")));
```

Answer (score 0):

The XElement has an Add method which appends nodes. You have to navigate to COLLEGE/location and call the method on this node.

[XElement.Add](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.add.aspx)